# Set a Repeater's TextBox value client side and pass it to ASP.NET code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I set a value in an input field client side (using Javascript). How can I access that value server side during post back?

The input field is an ASP.NET Web Forms TextBox in a Repeater.

Comment: Do you have example code? To be able to process the value in code behind, you need to post the input field inside a form.

Comment: Ok, I found that I had an attribute readonly="true" on the input, and it works just fine if I remove it. I don't know why though, I thought that the readonly attribute was only to prevent user input...